# Is there a difference between `Extract` and the intersection `&`?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
type abc = "a" | "b" | "c"
type af = "a" | "f"

type T0 = Extract<abc, af>;
//    type T0 = "a"
type T2 = abc & af
//    type T0 = "a"
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgRgYygXigIhmqAfdcu5oJoBQoksAZiupjupaWeNACoAMNAogB7ABOMBMAA88BABoqAPgDcJAPQKoKqAD0A-MwqsATDXFQAZFUXLVmkkA)

Is there any difference between `Extract` and `&`?

Comment: Where did you learn about that IntelliSense introspection comment syntax used in your playground? (`// ^?`)

Comment: I took the Intermediate Typescript course on FrontendMasters (https://frontendmasters.com/courses/intermediate-typescript/inference-q-a/) and found it some code block of the course website (https://www.typescript-training.com/course/intermediate-v1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [intersection operator `&`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is used to *extend* types (make a more specific type that is a subtype of each of the operands).

In contrast, the documentation says this about the [`Extract<Type, Union>` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

> Constructs a type by extracting from `Type` all union members that are assignable to `Union`.

In the case of literals (for example, `number` and `string` literals), these are equivalent: unions of literal types with less membership are more specific than unions with greater membership, so it simply works like the center, overlapping area of a Venn diagram in both cases:

[image: venn diagram A & B]

```ts
type Num = 1 | 2 | 3;
type Bin = 0 | 1;

type IntersectionN = Num & Bin; // 1
type ExtractionN = Extract<Num, Bin>; // 1
```

When considering object types, the two work very differently. Consider this example:

```ts
type A = {
  b: boolean;
  s: string;
};

type B = {
  b: boolean;
  n: number;
};

type IntersectionC = A & B;

declare const ci: IntersectionC;
ci.b // boolean
ci.n // number
ci.s // string

type ExtractionC = Extract<A, B>;

declare const ce: ExtractionC;
ce // never
```

The intersection of the two types creates a new object with the members of each input object.

In contrast, extracting from union `A` the members which are assignable to `B` yields `never` because `A` is not assignable to `B`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWygXigRigHygJi1AZgG4BYAKFEigCEBLAOxSgAZ81SzzLoBJe4CACcAzhADGwWgHt6MJvCQAyGgyJQA9OvRdw0AKIAPYIICGE6bKaHjZ4AB4FAGhX0AfGs3bO37lACCTADe5FBQAEYAXOFSUgA2ECb0HKHCUcLGDADmHAC+HDpU1EEh4VFhMfGJyVD0UfSIYUK5+RS6UHwCIuKSMgDCTAHK1C0AJuKxJoLQYjLpUGK0UR1CouZ9HAsAdGEaWuVxCfTkW4ye9QiNgse0m8K7UOmCWeQF+kama-T9qNYf9n7OajuF5kMZiCZTeazYDzCBRX62Cy9DbQM4QABuQnIQA)